# Can I use IF(ISNUMBER to find if a cell is 5 digits or more to show USA or Canada?

Tags: excel, if-statement, syntax

Could someone help me? I am learning Excel and I am trying to find a formula if a cell has 5 digits show USA, if not show Canada. But some cells have to 12345-6789 zip code, the result will show Canada.

Then I have Canada zip code R2H 0G2.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at IF formula. You can put another IF into the else result.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(--LEFT(A1,5)),"USA","CANADA")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @scottCraner!!!! It works, but for zip codes starting with Zeros such as 01373 in MA, it is showing Canada :(

Comment: What does the value look like in the formula bar.  is it `1373` or `'01373` if the latter you will need to change the format of the cells to text and not use the `'` as this will cause issues.